# Select from auto-complete options

Tags: html, powershell, autocomplete

I want to open next page in Powershell script by selecting first option in Auto-complete.

For example. When I open www.healthkartplus.com and type "Sporanox (100mg)". I want to select first option in Auto-complete.

I do not know how to select option from auto-complete so what I am trying is simply get first link on next page.

```
$ie = New-Object -COMObject InternetExplorer.Application
$ie.visible = $true
$site = $ie.Navigate("https://www.healthkartplus.com/search/all?name=Sporanox (100mg)")
$ie.ReadyState

    while ($ie.Busy -and $ie.ReadyState -ne 4){ sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
            $link = $null
            $link = $ie.Document.get_links() | where-object {$_.innerText -eq "Sporanox (100mg)"}
            $link.click()
```